# Remove JavaScript CSS overrides for printing

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, wordpress, slideshow

I am facing the following problem: I am trying to adapt the print version of a WordPress Theme. The theme contains a jQuery image slideshow which is generated from some included script, which I'm not supposed to change.

In HTML the slideshow is a ul with each li containing one image. The li elements have the classes "featured" and "slide_number_n" with n being the number of the slide (i.e. slide_number_1, slide_number_2 etc).

So the slideshow would look something like this:

```
<ul class="slideshow_container">
  <li class="featured slide_number_1" style="display:block"><img src="foo.jpg" /></li>
  <li class="featured slide_number_2" style="display:none"><img src="bar.jpg" /></li>
</ul>
```

If I look at the print version of the page (of course) it contains all the images from the slideshow, but our customer wants only the first display shown, so I tried changing it to do just that. But if I open the print version AFTER the first image has been displayed in the slideshow, I see no image at all, because the JS has overriden all the display values inline. I cannot get these JS changes reversed, not even using `!important` and `li[style]` in my print.css.

Is there a way to reverse the changes made by JS in the print.css?

Thank you and regards,
Julian

Answer (score 1):

`!important` should work.

See my example: http://jsfiddle.net/CqAXu/

If it isn't working then we need to see more of your code.

Comment: This would work, if I printed the page immediately after I load it. However it does not change the inline CSS that was changed by JS. IT just occured to me that it might be a browser specific problem. So far I have encountered it with FF and Opera.

Comment: http://jaredmcateer.com/test.html  Tested in chrome, on page load it hides the first div and shows the second... when I print the print.css hides all divs and only shows the one with the class `.someDiv`

Answer (score 0):

To print only the first one:

```
<style media="print">
    #slideshow_container .feature {
        display: none!important;
    }

    #slideshow_container :first-child {
        display: list-item!important;
    }
</style>

<ul id="slideshow_container">
    <li class="feature" style="display: none">Print</li>
    <li class="feature" style="display: list-item">Noprint, Current</li>
    <li class="feature" style="display: none">Noprint</li>
    <li class="feature" style="display: none">Noprint</li>
    <li class="feature" style="display: none">Noprint</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Again, same problem. Works if I print the page before jQuery made any changes. But as soon as jQuery has set the first child to `style="display:none"`, css seems unable to override that.

Comment: It should override it, unless it is set to style="display:none!important".

Comment: It seems, the browsers don't reload the page when generating a print version, but rather load the print.css on page load. At least that would explain, why JS could overload my CSS.